# Custom action bar with ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS

Tags: android, tabs, navigation, android-actionbar, custom-titlebar

I have a navigation tabs in my Android app that works great with the view pager, (Android 4.0.3)  something like:

```
|======title bar with icon======|

|==(tab 1)|(tab 2)|(tab3)|(tab4)==|
```

This works fine with the help of:

```
actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

The setting of styles like:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

The real problem its that I need to customize the title (first row) of the action bar; but when I try to edit it with the following code:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title_main);
```

Just that say it in this page http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/

The LogCat throw this exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.test.app/com.test.app.activity.MainActivity}:  android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features

So I try to just ONLY customize the Title bar and dont use the `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);`

And works! the title bar was customized but in the line `actionBar = getActionBar();` the LogCat throws a nullPointerException (I understand why, I only need HOW TO customize the action bar (the title) and use it with ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS at the same time.

Solutions like "I put a view over the layout and works, its so simple!" not its a efficient solution, sorry.

Comment: I found a workaround that works, but I'm not sure if works totally; using the following code:   actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.title_main);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);